# Struggled with moment-timezone offset magic

Tags: timezone, momentjs, timezone-offset

Trying to understand logic behind the magic of timezones, offsets, etc... Looking at example of [finding an offset with moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/offset/) library, and can't understand why offset is different in both cases?

```
moment.tz.zone('America/Los_Angeles').offset(1403465838805); // 420
moment.tz.zone('America/Los_Angeles').offset(1388563200000); // 480
```

Comment: Simply [Daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), what is exactly unclear to you?

Comment: Actually you have answered my question, thank you :)